# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt[n]{2} - 1)$

Tags: limits, radicals

I am trying to find the limit of:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt[n]{2} - 1)$$

I know it should be very simple but I don't seem to get it.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just remember to put in $\LaTeX$ in between dollar signs on this website.

Comment: Maple says ln(2)

Comment: Youu can rewrite your expression $$\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}$$. Then it comes easily.

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that we can define the (natural) logarithm of a number $x>0$ as

$$L(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}$$

Although it may take a time, it is not awfully complicated to prove this function indeed has the defining properties of the logarithm.

$$\tag 1 L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)$$
$$\tag 2 L(x^a)=a L(x)$$
$$\tag 3 1-\frac 1 x \leq L(x)\leq x-1$$
$$\tag 4\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{L(x+1)}{x}=1$$
$$\tag 5 L'(x)=\frac 1 x$$

Note that $1\Rightarrow 2 \;(a\in \Bbb Z)\Rightarrow 3\Rightarrow 4\Rightarrow 5$.

On the other hand, a naïve use of L'Höpital's rule, gives

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}\mathop=\limits^{\frac 0 0}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h\log x}{1}=\log x$$

If you're interested in the proofs, just let me know.

Comment: Invoking L'Hopital (with no umlaut) to prove that the limit of $(f(t)-f(0))/t$ when $t\to0$ is $f'(0)$ is, strictly speaking, making a logical circle. This might be what "naïve" at the end refers to.

Comment: @Did Yes, indeed. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several answers and comments suggesting L'Hospital's
rule.

In fact, it is a bit easier - you only need the definition of the
derivative.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}= \lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{2^x-2^0}{x-0}$$

So this expression is precisely the value of the derivative of
$f(x)=2^x$ at $x=0$.

If you already know that the derivative of $f(x)=2^x$ is
$f'(x)= 2^x  \ln 2$, then you have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}= f'(0)=\ln 2.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $$\lim _ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2^x-2^0}{x-0}=\ln2$$

ADDED:$$2^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{\ln2}{n}}=1+\frac{\ln2}{n}+\mathrm{O}\left ( \frac{1}{n^2} \right )$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write the limit as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{2}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$
and note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2}=1$. Now use L'Hospital's
Rule and clark's hint.

Comment: Or just use the definition of the derivative for $2^x$.

Comment: Invoking L'Hopital to prove that the limit of $(f(t)-f(0))/t$ when $t\to0$ is $f'(0)$ is, strictly speaking, making a logical circle.

Answer (score 1):

Take the *function* $\,f(x):=x(\sqrt[x] 2-1)\,$ and let us apply L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^{1/x}-1}{1/x}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\log 2\cdot 2^{1/x}}{\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log 2\cdot 2^{1/x}=\log 2$$

Of course, the limit will be the same if we take

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\,\,,\,n\in\Bbb N\,$$

Comment: Invoking L'Hopital to prove that the limit of $(f(t)-f(0))/t$ when $t\to0$ is $f'(0)$ is, strictly speaking, making a logical circle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41874/discussion-on-answer-by-donantonio-finding-lim-n-to-infty-n-sqrtn2). Cool it, dudes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\frac1x$. Then the limit becomes $$\lim_{\frac1t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^t-1}t=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{2^t-1}t$$And use the definition of the derivative to get that the answer is $\ln 2$.